# OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.4 "Ghost Servers" Cannot Be Removed

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have several "instances" of a "ghost" server appearing in my Finder window. They appear to be duplicates of the computer I am working on (my iMac). I can't find a way to remove them from the list, and their presence seems to be interfering with the launch of a program which states that it's license is already running on one of the instances listed.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5503373/Ghosts.tiff

How do I exorcize these ghosts?